# Как обойтись без CloudPayments?

Tags: java, платежи

Всем привет! У меня вопрос про то, как реализовать платежную систему в Java без использования систем как CloudPayments. Вот описание:
В приложении реализуется система оплаты ежемесячной подписки, а так же перевод средств при оплате заказа с карты клиента на счет конкретного заведения.

> Я сначала подумал что сервер можно обойти, но в процессе чтения наткнулся на рекомендацию проверять платежи на своем сервере 
>   То есть запрос на CloudPayments API можно сделать без проблем и из приложения, но тогда в приложении будут открыты кое-какиеие данные
>   а именно 
>   MERCHANT_PUBLIC_ID (ваш уникальный номер в системе), MERCHANT_API_PASS (ваш пароль) 
>   "Крайне нежелательно отправлять данные для оплаты с мобильного устройства напрямую в API CloudPayments. Необходимо держать учетные данные для доступа к API на нашем сервере, а в мобильном приложении поддерживать принцип тонкого клиента;"

Что можно сделать? Какие библиотеки можно использовать? Я просто никогда не работал с платежными библиотеками в Java. Прошу помочь с идеями.

Comment: сначала с банком договор заключите, чтобы работать в обход IPSP)

Comment: реализуйте собственный API на стороне сервера, который собственно будет общаться с платежной системой. А из приложения соответственно вызывайте свой сервер, а не платежную систему на прямую